# Parse HTML from JSON in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I started to learn AngularJS today and so far I am doing well. But I encountered a problem and I can't seem to find an answer. What I'm trying to do is to print html string `<p>Text</p>` as formatted `Text`. So far Angular prints it as plain `<p>Text</p>`.

My code is as follows:

JS

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', []);

blogApp.controller('blogPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('wp-json/posts').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.postsLoaded = 'visible-lg';
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<article id="post-{{post.ID}}" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-class="postsLoaded">

    <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a title="Link do {{post.title}}" rel="bookmark" href="{{post.link}}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <img ng-src="{{post.featured_image.source}}">
        {{post.content}}
    </div>
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <ul class="categories"><li ng-repeat="category in post.terms.category"><a href="{{category.link}}">{{category.name}}</a></li></ul>
    </footer>
</article>
```

My problem is with `{{post.content}}`. I wanted to try `ng-bind-unsafe`, but it was removed. I also tried `ng-bind-html="post.content"`, but it didn't work.

I am using Angular 1.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). For example with your content you'd use this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
```

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way. By default, the resulting HTML content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service. To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core Angular). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I tried using it, as I said in my question, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Newbie's mistake, I didn't include `ngSanitize` (as seen in my code) ;-) Works now, thanks!